# How to handle file changes when browser caching is enabled?

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I found the following cache htaccess rules but I have 2 questions

1. Is the one for PHP included in this? Is is under the "html" since it runs on server and results are shown to client?
2. Second question is let's say I made some css changes to theme.css. I suppose that a visitor will not get the new version, so should I add it something like `theme.css?7362340` with a different sequence every time I made changes ?

Here is the htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: 1. PHP may be included based on these rules.  Check the headers of the page with curl.
2. Yes, adding a unique string or version indicator as a querystring parameter is a good strategy.

Comment: @user2182349 Hi, thank you for the answer, but "may be included" is not the optimum for me..